# Display only date and no time in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting date and time from db but i need to display only date

this is my view code

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
```

Comment: Add a `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]` to your property

Comment: Or simply `@item.Date.ToShortDateString()`